# How to use StructureMap to inject repository classes to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, repository-pattern

In the current application I am working on I have a custom ControllerFactory class that create a controller and automatically sets the Elmah ErrorHandler.

```
public class BaseControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController( RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName ) {
        var controller = base.CreateController( requestContext, controllerName );
        var c = controller as Controller;
        if ( c != null ) {
            c.ActionInvoker = new ErrorHandlingActionInvoker( new HandleErrorWithElmahAttribute() );
        }
        return controller;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance( RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType ) {
        try {
            if ( ( requestContext == null ) || ( controllerType == null ) )
                return base.GetControllerInstance( requestContext, controllerType );

            return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance( controllerType );
        }
        catch ( StructureMapException ) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave() );
            throw new Exception( ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave() );
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use StructureMap to inject some code in my controllers. For example I would like to automatically inject repository classes in them.

I have already created my repository classes and also I have added a constructor to the controller that receive the repository class

```
public FirmController( IContactRepository contactRepository ) {
    _contactRepository = contactRepository;
}
```

I have then registered the type within StructureMap

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize( x => {
    x.For<IContactRepository>().Use<MyContactRepository>();
});
```

How should I change the code in the CreateController method to have the `IContactRepository` concrete class injected in the `FirmController`?

**EDIT**:

I have changed the BaseControllerFactory to use Structuremap. But I get an exception on the line

```
return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance( controllerType );
```

Any hint?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you calling your Initialize code in the app_start before you set the custom controller factory? I.E. StaticClass.InitializeStructureMap(); Then ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new BaseControllerFactory());

Comment: Good catch. I was calling the initialize code after setting the custom controller factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before typing in the solution, I would recommend using the Container type to initialize SM rather than ObjectFactory

The best way to accomplish this would be to have a class subclassed from the Registry class in StructureMap framework. so, my Registry would be something like

```
public class MyAppRegistry : Registry
{
     public MyAppRegistry()
     {
        For<IContactRepository>().Use<MyContactRepository>();
     }
}
```

and then tell SM to use this Registry during configuration.

```
var container = new Container(x=>x.AddRegistry(new MyAppRegistry());
```

this would be done from the Application_Start in the Global.asax. After the above line, set the ControllerBuilder in mvc to use the BaseControllerFactory. Now SM should be able to resolve all dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do there are any difference between using a container and the `ObjectFactory.Initialize` method? I have slightly modified the code and I am actually using the Initialize method with the AddRecistry inside..

Comment: sorry I meant `AddRegistry()`

Comment: You are welcome Lorenzo! The ObjectFactory is just a static wrapper around the Container. So, when you call Initialize, it would call the Container's ctor passing in your initialization expression. Another thing to be aware of is that if Initialize is called again on ObjectFactory, it would wipe out all previous registrations. So, with a Container it is much cleaner as you can only call Configure after the initial configuration, which adds to the existing registrations. Good luck in your project!